# Convert Unicode code point to UTF-8 sequence

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I am not sure I've got my nomenclature right, so please correct me :)

I've received a text file representing a Pāli dictionary: a list of words separated by newline `\n` (0x0a) characters.  Supposedly, some of the special letters are encoded using UTF-8, but I doubt that.

Loading this text file into any of my editors (vim, Notepad, TextEdit, ..) shows quite scrambled text, for example

```
mhiti
```

A closer look at the actual bytes then reveal the following (using `hexdump -C`)

```
0a 0a 1e 6d 68 69 74 69 0a 0a  ...mhiti..
```

which seems to me the Unicode code point `U+1E6D` ("ṭ" or LATIN SMALL LETTER T WITH DOT BELOW).  That particular letter has UTF-8 encoding `e1 b9 ad`.

My question: is there a tool which helps me convert this particular file into actual UTF-8 encoding?  I tried `iconv` but without success; I looked briefly into a Python script but would think there's an easier way to get this done.  It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607413/c-library-to-convert-unicode-code-points-to-utf8) is a useful link for this problem, but isn't there a tool that can get this done?  Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Just to make things a little bit more entertaining, there seem to be actual UTF-8 encoded characters scattered throughout as well.  For example, the word "[ākiñcaññāyatana](http://www.palidictionary.appspot.com/browse/%C4%81/%C4%81ki%C3%B1ca%C3%B1%C3%B1%C4%81yatana)" has the following sequence of bytes

```
01 01 6b 69 c3 b1 63 61 c3 b1 c3 b1 01 01 79 61 74 61 6e 61
ā     k  i  ñ     c  a  ñ     ñ     ā     y  a  t  a  n  a
```

where the "ā" is encoded by its Unicode code point U-0101, and the "ñ" is encoded by the UTF-8 sequence \xc3b1 which has Unicode code point U-00F1.

**EDIT:** Here's one that I can't quite figure out what it's supposed to be:

```
01 1e 37 01 01 76 61 6b 61
?        ā     v  a  k  a
```

I can only guess, but that too doesn't make sense.  The Unicode code point U+011e is a "Ğ" (UTF-8 \xc49e) but that's not a Pāli character AFAIK; then a "7" follows which doesn't make sense in a word.  Then the Unicode code point U+1E37 is a "ḷ" (UTF-8 \xe1b8b7) which is a valid Pāli character.  But that would leave the first byte \x01 by itself.  If I had to guess I would think this is the name "Jīvaka" but that would not match the bytes.  **LATER:** According to the author, this is "Āḷāvaka" — so assuming the heuristics of character encoding from above, again a \x00 is missing.  Adding it back in

```
01 00 1e 37 01 01 76 61 6b 61
Ā     ḷ     ā     v  a  k  a
```

Are there "compressions" that remove \x00 bytes from UTF-16 encoded Unicode files?

Comment: Yeah, that is clearly not UTF-8. If that is indeed "ṭhiti", then it does not look like any sane Unicode encoding to me.

Comment: You could try interpreting every 2-byte sequence that starts with a byte > 127 as a Unicode codepoint. But that's a sketchy encoding scheme at best. If you could show us a bit more of the hexdump (together with the expected text), we might find a pattern there.

Comment: @JoachimSauer and it would not even work for the example given...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: D'oh! Right ...

Comment: This looks like UTF-16 with all the zero bytes removed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks for validating my suspicion :)

Comment: @JoachimSauer: That's what I thought at first but I think I'll have to be more restrictive.  For example, \x0101 is a "ā" character but still > \x007f.  I'll probably constrain to [a-zA-Z] and interpret everything outside of that as a Unicode code point.

Comment: @Joni: It does.  See my answer to Joachim.  An alternative approach would be to insert all the \x00 bytes where I suspect them to be missing, i.e. before every [a-zA-Z] ...

Comment: This continues to look like a "corruption" more than an actual encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the end this was my own fault, somehow.  Browsing to [this file](https://files.myopera.com/Pesala/Backups/Pali.tlx) showed a very mangled and broken version of the original UTF-16 encoded file; the "Save as" menu from the browser then saved that broken file which created the initial question for this thread.

It seems that a web browser tries to display that UTF-16 encoded file, removes non-printable characters like \x00 and converts some others to UTF-8, thus completely mangling the original file.

Using `wget` to fetch the file fixed the problem, and I could convert it nicely into UTF-8 and use it further.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming in this context that "[ṭhiti](http://www.palidictionary.appspot.com/browse/%E1%B9%AD/%E1%B9%ADhiti)" makes sense as the contents of that file.

From your description, it looks like that file encodes characters < U+0080 as a single byte and characters > U+0100 as two-byte big-endian. That's not decodable, in general; two linefeeds (U+000A, U+000A) would have the same encoding as GURMUKHI LETTER UU (U+0A0A).

There's no invocation of `iconv` that'll decode it for you; you'll either need to take the heuristics you know, either based on character ranges or ordering in the file, to write a custom decoder (or ask for another copy in a standard encoding).

Comment: Thanks Joe for the confirmation as well :)  Yes, this is supposed to be the Pāli word "ṭhiti".  See my answers above as to what I think I'll do about this...

Comment: Yes, inserting `\x00` before every `[\na-zA-Z]` and outputting the next two bytes as-is otherwise would be a great first step. That can be piped through `iconv -f utf-16be -t utf-8` and inspected for exceptions.